# Selection Of Range While Doing Binary Search?

Tags: arrays, search, binary

During the binary search talking in genric term in any problem on the basis of some condition we we either move left half of the array or the right half of the array.But my concern remain while solving the binary search problem that suppose that following the condition my area of interest of search part of array is left half of the array so we change the end pointer to the **"end=mid-1" or "end=mid" and vice versa for right half of array.**

So my concern here how to decide whether to put end=mid-1 or end=mid because it always bother me and I have to make hit and trail.

Comment: I really don't think it matters...

Comment: @iAmOren I found some of the question answer is not getting accepted

Comment: I didn't understand your reply.  Please rephrase - thanks!